# Reload background-image from PHP file using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a `<body style="<?php include("gallery.php"); ?>"` where gallery.php holds a random array of images, echoing the URL upon each reload.

I would like to have a button to refresh the background image of the body.

I currently am able to do one reload of the image, since the new URL is echoed.

EG:

```
$(".refresh").click(function() {
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(<?php include("gallery.php"); ?>)");
});
```

But after the inclusion of the gallery file in the script, it is always the same url.

**EDIT**
My PHP is as follows:

```
$bg = array(
    array( "url" => "url_1" ),
    array( "url" => "url_2" ),
    ...
);


for ($i=0;$i<1;$i++) {
    $id = array_rand($bg);
    echo "{$bg[$id]['url']}";
    unset($ad[$id]);
};
```

Comment: Try separating client and server code and using AJAX.

Comment: What is the output of `gallery.php`? Also, try to get this in a Javascript array...so that you can just replace the values from the array...no need of ajax as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be in an another way and `gallery.php` could outputs an image (not just a url), So you can access `gallery.php` like this :

```
$(".refresh").click(function() { 
    $("body").css("background-image", 'url("http://www.mysite.com/gallery.php?'+Math.random()+'")'); 
});
```

Using `Math.random()` will passes a random number to avoid caching.

So in `gallery.php` you have something like :

```
$bg = array(
    array( "url" => "url_1" ),
    array( "url" => "url_2" ),
    ...
);

shuffle($bg); // Random order

echo file_get_contents($bg[0]['url']);
//instead of echo $url;
```

Comment: According to the question `gallery.php` only outputs an URL, not an image. This will not work.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider oh i didn't noticed it ;)

Comment: @Omid How would I alter my PHP script? I currently have a loop that passes each url and outputs it

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv Let me see, You have a set of images in your PHP file. Also have an index file that has some elements with background images. Each element should have a random background image from image set ?

Comment: @Omid So I have the PHP file with the url of the images, and an index file with the call on the `<body>` to get the background image. I need a button to refresh the background image url without refreshing the page.

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv I see that, but you didn't answer my question. You want to get background images in random order or each image is for specific element ?

Comment: @Omid Sorry, totally misread your question. Random is the aim.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".refresh").click(function() { 
    $.get('gallery.php', function(data) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url('"+data+"')"); 
    }
});
```

PHP is server side scripting language and Javascript is client side scripting language. We can't use them like you were using. But you can send request from client to server to faciliate body with URL.

Comment: @AspiringAqib This works once, and then the refresh wont reload again

Answer (score 0):

IMO Ajax is overkill and piping all images through a php script creates unnecessary memory overhead. For very large images it could even create memory problems on your webserver. The best method would be to put all images in a javascript array, as already suggested. You can have `gallery.php` output an array of URLs to the images.

```
[ 'http://url1/', 'http://url2', ... ] // etc
```

Then you can call it in your file like this:

```
<script type="javascript">
  var backgroundImages = <?php include("gallery.php"); ?>;
  function refresh() {
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + backgroundImages[Math.round(Math.random() * backgroundImages.length)] + ")"); 
  }
  $(function() { refresh(); });
  $(".refresh").click(refresh);
</script>
```

Comment: Commonly, When we use a `php` file want to add Expire headers and compressing images. Just selecting an image in random order would not be the matter.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider  Using the include("gallery.php") echoes out a URL. I've added my PHP to see where I can change it to make this work :]